# Core Reporting API v4 sampling limit for click data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

After how many clicks will the Core Reporting API start to sample the click data, when using `samplingLevel=LARGE`?

I'm trying to retrieve data from a large account (i.e. more than 30,000 clicks/day on average) and the number of clicks doesn't always match what I can see on Google Analytics. This, however, seems to happen only on this large account, and not every day. Strangely, on those days where the click count doesn't match, transactions and revenue match what I can see in Google Analytics.

In my query, I'm only trying to retrieve the data for a given account, without applying any filter.

EDIT: If I don't retrieve data aggregated at the account level ― thus not including `ga:adwordsCampaignID`, `ga:adwordsAdGroupID` and `ga:adwordsCriteriaID` in the dimensions ― I can retrieve all the clicks.

EDIT2: If add the `ga:deviceCategory` dimension, along with `ga:adwordsCampaignID`, `ga:adwordsAdGroupID` and `ga:adwordsCriteriaID` I can retrieve all clicks. I'm not sure if this can help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has a cardinality of 50K after that you ll receive (others)

Based on the "EDIT" i can safely assume the reason is that when a click doesn't have an 'ga:adwordsCampaignID' associated with it, it ll not retrieve that click. This happened to me with custom dimensions.

EDIT: Try using the 'include-empty-rows' parameter on your query. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#includeEmptyRows

Comment: Hi Marco, thank you for your answer! How is it possible that a click doesn't have an associated campaign, adgroup or criteria id if I'm retrieving data for an Adwords account?

Comment: @Gianluca you would be amazed on the amount of information that is send with wrong fields. But this reply is not helping, try with only one of those dimension at a time and see if only one of those is the problem o all.